# AppStore rejection because of scraping or using unofficial API

Tags: ios, app-store

I am currently making an app using Tinder API.  It's very similar to those auto-liker apps that leverage Tinder API as well.

My app was rejected on the ground that the user is not presented Terms of Use Agreement before accepting to send login info to Facebook for use of Tinder token.

Now that is fine, but Apple also called me and said that 
"There are rules not written in guidelines, and we do not accept apps that use unofficial APIs and scrapes websites that you do not own."

I checked the guidelines, and only things written there are that

1. Do not use unofficial API - I interpret as non documented iOS API.
2. Do not scrape Apple websites

Furthermore, there are dozens of Tinder auto-liker type apps, and yet more apps that scrape third party websites.

Why is the Apple review team telling me those things?

Has anyone else ever heard from the AppStore review team that:

- We can only use "Official" APIs
- We cannot scrape third party websites
- There are rejection rules that are not written in the guidelines.

Any feedback is appreciated.

EDIT

- The point here is that is there an unofficial non-written rejection
  guidelines.  I believe that is a gray issue since it can be grounds
  for lawsuits and I want to get experiences of other developers if
  they have received similar explanation over voice calls.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because app-store approval is off-topic.  Only Apple can comment on their approval policies - If Apple are telling you something, why would anyone here be able to tell you anything different? It doesn't matter what apps have been approved in the past. What matters is what Apple are telling you *now*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after three phone conversations with Apple, the rejection reason was made more clear.  It has nothing to do with "non-written" guidelines... there is no such thing.  I am not sure why the reviewer mentioned in one of the conversations.

Basically I was exposing some data for Tinder users gained for API in a certain way, and Apple thought that I needed to gain their consent.  Now, the other Tinder users are not users of my app, so it is impossible to gain their consent.  That was the real rejection reason.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, any app that provides login-registration to users, needs to have a *Terms of Service* and a *Privacy Policy* page displayed to user before registration. Just add these 2 and resubmit the app for review.